# Change Row Color based on td value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a table that gets populated from a database. I have 2 conditions that i need to apply

1. Apply Zebra striping to the Table (Completed)
2. Change Row color to red based td value

​`

```
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"><input type="text" value="One"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"><input type="text" value="One"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"><input type="text" value="Zero"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"><input type="text" value="One"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
    <td class="status"><input type="text" value="Zero"></td>
    <td class>Received</td>
</tr>
```

​`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("tr.alt:even").css("background-color", "#f0f8ff");
$("tr.alt:odd").css("background-color", "#fcfceb");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.status.val():contains("Zero")').closest('tr.alt').css('background-color', '#cd0000');
});
```

I wanna change the row color based on the input value

`<td class="status"><input type="text" value="One"></td>`

[Here is a fiddle of what I've done so far](http://jsfiddle.net/MMEhc/146/)

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: With CSS, there is no need for JavaScript to do this unless you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Actually the `<td>`-tag doesn't have an attribute called `value`. You could use a user defined attribute like this: `<td class="status" data-value="One">1</div>`. This is perfectly valid HTML and works in all browsers.

Comment: Note that you don't need to document ready handlers, you can put all your code in the first one. And if you apply the `alt` class to the `<table>` or `<tbody>` element then you don't need to apply it to every `<tr>` - you can still select them for the striping with `$("table.alt tr:even")`.

Comment: Sorry i got my questiong wrong... I wanna chnge the row color based on the input value="One"

`<td class="status"><input type="text" value="One"></td>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the tr (you're using v 1.6.4 instead of latest so we need bind instead of on)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("tr.alt:even").addClass("even");
    $("tr.alt:odd").addClass("odd");
    $('td.status input').bind('change keyup', function(){
        var tr=$(this).closest('tr');

        if ($(this).val()=='Zero') tr.addClass('zero');       
        else tr.removeClass('zero');

    }).trigger('change'); // the trigger is to run this action on load
});
​
tr.odd
{
    background-color:#fcfceb;
}

tr.even
{
    background-color:#f0f8ff;
}

tr.odd.zero
{
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
tr.even.zero
{
    background-color:#cc0000;
}
```

Your HTML is a bit messed up though. You have missing quotes and `<td class>` is invalid.

http://jsfiddle.net/MMEhc/158/

EDIT: Updated version to suit the values being changed manually, not just those that are outputted (as I understood the question to be)

http://jsfiddle.net/MMEhc/159/

You'll see I moved the background colours out of the HTML and into the CSS to make it easier to manipulate. I also adjusted the red for even or odd rows.

Comment: try it with your HTML fixed, I've added the jsfiddle to my answer

Comment: The problem comes when someone changes am input from one --> Zero that row doesn't get affected by the red background

Comment: I do not know which rows will have a Zero value seeded in

Comment: Oh you didn't say this, you said the values come from the database. I will change it.

Comment: Sorry i'm really new to javascript how will i run this action onload

Comment: Just like in the jsfiddle. Read this http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready() if you're confused about that. Other than that, the red backgrounds run on load because I triggered the bind I created in the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks... I finally got it to work... For some reason IE9 was acting up... used `jQuery(function($)` and started working

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MMEhc/148/)**

```
$('td.status[value=Zero]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

**Edit: Based on comments and change in OP**

To change the whole `row with the given criteria of td` you can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MMEhc/172/)**

```
$('td.status[value=Zero]').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Or `$('td.status[value="Zero"]').closest('tr').css('background-color', '#cd0000');` given that the OP wants to change the whole row.

Comment: Sorry i got my questiong wrong... I wanna chnge the row color based on the input value `<td class="status"><input type="text" value="One"></td>`

Comment: that's trying to find a td with the class of status and a value of Zero