# Jquery Event function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

My Requirement is if there is a table in that table there are certain rows and columns.

1) suppose there is a column named as Estimated hours.

2) If the Estimated Hours is less than 30 Hours then that particular row should visible in Red color.

can anyone please help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried anything out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Row Color based on td value using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547616/change-row-color-based-on-td-value-using-jquery)

Comment: -1! did you gogle that? http://bit.ly/1hCSvsn

Answer (score 1):

I did this using css and jquery

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Work</th>
        <th>WorkHr</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xxx</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>yyy</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>zzz</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>60</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.select {
    outline: thin solid black;
    background-color:red;
}
table, th, td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('td').filter(function () {
    if ($(this).text() > 30) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("select");
    }
});
```

Check out the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mFwG9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"   src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = $("tbody tr").size();
        for ( var i = 1; i < count ; i++ ) {
            var estimatedHours = parseInt($(".estimated_hours_"+i).text());

            if(estimatedHours <= 30){
                $('.estimated_hours_'+i).parent().css('background-color','red');
            }
        }
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <table border="1">
     <tr>
        <th>test1</th>
        <th>test2</th>
        <th>Estimated hours</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td class="estimated_hours_1">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td class="estimated_hours_2">40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td class="estimated_hours_3">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td>body1</td>
       <td class="estimated_hours_4">50</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```