# Change Row Color based on td variable value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547616/change-row-color-based-on-td-value-using-jquery). In my particular case, I have Machines in different Rooms. So let's say my table contains columns: room, machine, etc. One room may contain many machines.

I need to change the row color when the `room_name` changes.

I tried this but it did not work.

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById("tblMain");
if (tbl != null) {
  if (tbl.rows[0] != null) {
    var room = document.getElementById("tblMain").rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
    tbl.rows[0].style.backgroundColor = "#f1fafa";
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    if (room == document.getElementById("tblMain").rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;)
      tbl.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#f1fafa";
  }

  room = document.getElementById("tblMain").rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable dataTable" id="tblMain">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Machine</th>
      <th>Serial Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($assignations as $assignation): ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?= $assignation->has('room') ? $assignation->room->name : '-' ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $assignation->has('machine') ? $assignation->machine->name : '' ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $assignation->has('machine') ? $assignation->machine->serial_number : '' ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is an example of the output I need:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
<tr>
    <td>room 1</td>
    <td>machine 1</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
    <td>room 2</td>
    <td>machine 2</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
    <td>room 2</td>
    <td>machine 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>room 4</td>
    <td>machine 4</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
    <td>room 7</td>
    <td>machine 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show the associated HTML table too

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to add an example of compiled HTML (with real values), with pictures of what you get and what you want to achieve

Comment: thanks Fabio. I added a snippet